# The product and metric topologies on $X = \{1, 2, \ldots, n\}^{\Bbb Z}$ coincide

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, product-space

> Consider $X = \{1, 2, \ldots, n\}^{\Bbb Z}$. We can endow $X$ with a topology in at least two ways:
>
> 1. Let $\tau_1$ be the product topology on $X$, due to the discrete topology on $\{1, 2, \ldots, n\}$.
> 2. Let $\tau_2$ be the metric topology on $X$, where the metric $d: X\times X \to \Bbb R$ is given by $d(x,y) = 2^{-k}$ if $k = \max\{j: x_i = y_i \text{ for } |i| \le j\}$, and $d(x,x) = 0$.

I'd like to show that $\tau_1= \tau_2$.

$\tau_1$ is generated by the basis $$\mathcal B_1 = \left\{\prod_{i\in \Bbb Z} U_i: U_i \subset \{1, \ldots, n\}, U_i = \{1, \ldots, n\} \text{ for all but finitely many } i\in \Bbb Z \right\}$$
and $\tau_2$ is generated by the basis consisting of open balls in $X$ (with respect to $d$). The following proposition from point-set topology should be helpful:

> *Proposition.* $\tau \supset \tau'$, i.e., $\tau$ is *finer* than $\tau'$ if and only if for all $x\in X$, and each basic open set $B'$ of $\tau'$ containing $x$, there exists a basic open set $B$ of $\tau$ such that $x\in B\subset B'$.

- Now, pick any $x\in X$. I shall try to show $\tau_1 \supset \tau_2$ first. Suppose $x\in B(y,r)$, where $y\in X$ and $r > 0$. We want $B\in \mathcal B_1$ such that $x\in B \subset B(y,r)$.
- To finish, we need $\tau_2 \supset \tau_1$. Pick any $x\in X$, and a basic open set $\prod_{i\in \Bbb Z} U_i$ containing $x$ (note that $U_i = \{1, \ldots, n\}$ for all but finitely many $i$). It shall suffice to find $r > 0$ such that $x\in B(x,r) \subset \prod_{i\in \Bbb Z} U_i$. There exists $m \ge 1$ such that for every $|i| \ge m$, $U_i$ is $\{1, \ldots, n\}$.

As it stands, both directions are incomplete. Please note that I ask for pointers and hints to complete my work and not necessarily a detailed solution (which may be found in possible duplicates).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specific hints:

Fix a $y$ and an $r>0$. There is a $k$, $2^{-k}<r$. We can find a $\mathcal{B}_1$-neighbourhood of $y$ by setting finitely many coordinates $i$ equal to $y_i$, and letting all higher coordinates vary. Think about the specific meaning of $d(x,y)<2^{-k}$. You might also want to reverse engineer the solution to the other direction.

For the other direction, say $J$ is the largest index for which $U_J\subsetneq\{1,\cdots,n\}$. How does $B(x,2^{-J-1})$ relate to the $\mathcal{B}_1$-neighbourhood of $x$?

---

Overkill abstraction:

It is a general theorem that the countable **topological** product of metric spaces $(X_i;\rho_i)_{i\in\Bbb N}$ is *metrizable* via the metric: $$\varrho(a,b)=\sum_{i=1}^\infty2^{-i}\color{blue}{\frac{\rho_i(a_i,b_i)}{1+\rho_i(a_i,b_i)}}$$

Really, we only need a bounded $\color{blue}{blue}$ metric that yields the same topology on $X_i$ as $\rho_i$. The ratio I give there is the 'canonical' way to do this, but any set of uniformly bounded metrics with equivalent topology will do. To that end, let's replace the $\color{blue}{blue}$ with some uniformly bounded metrics $\rho'_i$ on $X_i$ such that $(X_i;\rho_i)$ has the same topology as $(X_i;\rho'_i)$: $$\varrho(a,b)=\sum_{i=1}^\infty2^{-i}\color{blue}{\rho'_i(a_i,b_i)}$$

The theorem can be found in Royden's real analysis, exercise $12$, chapter $16$ (available on the web).

You can try this if you want. You need to check $\varrho$ is indeed a metric, and you need to check the topology is the same as the product topology. You should also check that the 'canonical' choice of $\rho'_i$ I introduced at the start does actually induce the same topology.

This applies to your problem by allowing the discrete metric on each $X_i=\{1,\cdots,n\}$. Well, not directly, but $d$ is equivalent to the induced $\varrho$.

Comment: 1. $\mathcal{B}_1$-neighbourhood of $x$, right (not $y$)?

Comment: 2. There was a typo in the definition of the metric (in my post) if I am not wrong (also in the book). Please see the edit and let me know if it's correct.

Comment: @esoteric-elliptic Regarding the first comment, I meant ‘neighbourhood of $y$’. We are given a metric ball neighbourhood and want to squeeze a $\mathcal{B}_1$-neighbourhood *of $y$* inside this ball. We only need to look at other $x$ to determine one neighbourhood is indeed a subset of the other.

Comment: @esoteric-elliptic As for the second comment, I actually didn’t notice the typo at first. Your edited version of the metric is the metric I first read and was working with in my post, I guess I knew what you meant without spotting the $\le k$ typo. So, I don’t think I need to change anything in my answer.

Comment: Re the first comment: but it turns out the said neighborhood also contains $x$, right? We need this, if we are to use the proposition I have stated in my post.

Comment: @esoteric-elliptic A basic neighbourhood of $x$ can be reduced to $B(x,r)$ for some $r$. I’ve been using the letter $x$ for a different purpose and I’ve only distinguished $y$ as a centre of the metric ball. All we need to do is find a neighbourhood of $y$ in $\tau_1$ that is contained in the ball.

Comment: After all, if $x\in B(y,r)$ then $B(x,r-d(x,y))$ is a metric ball neighbourhood of $x$ (with positive radius, note) that is fully contained in $B(y,r)$. So it suffices to solve the inclusion problem for $\tau_1$-neighbourhoods of $a$ contained in balls $B(a,r)$, where I use $a=y$ in my post but you could just as well use $a=x$.